# Why "On implique personne d'autre là-dedans" implies there won't be any more people involved without using negative adverbs in the sentence?

Tags: grammaire, adverbes

I came across this sentence while checking what `là-dedans` meant:

> On implique personne d'autre là-dedans

And according to the translation it means *We aren't going to involve any more people in this* but I don't see any negative adverbs in the sentence. I'm still a novice at the language but I thought such a sentence would use *n'on pas* instead. Why is it not using negative adverbs to turn an affirmative statement into a negative statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence should rather be written *on n'implique personne d'autre là dedans* which happens to be pronounced exactly the same way.

The negative is given by the *ne ... personne d'autre* compound, but can be reduced to *personne d'autre* in spoken French, e.g.:

> *On ne mêle personne d'autre à ça.* Standard French
>
> *On mêle personne d'autre à ça.* Colloquial French

Comment: Thanks, that clears up a few doubts but I have a question, how should I know if there is a reduced "ne" in a sentence? it may be basic but if I don't see a negation, I immediately try to make sense of it as if it were an affirmative sentence.

Comment: You know if a sentence is negative because at least one of the splitted negative parts remains. (*il ne pleut pas* = *Il pleut pas*, *je ne vois personne* = *je vois personne*). Note that your sentence is not completely negative but more a restrictive statement. *Nobody else is involved in it by us*